# Finding a double in the workspace by name and assigning it to a new variable

Tags: matlab

I've got a very simple question. I've got some very large files which I'm iteratively uploading. I assign part of each file's name to a variable  `ID`. Say, in my example, I've already successfully done that, so I have:

`ID = 100 % participant number 100`

In addition, I've got many different double type variables in my workspace, of different length. They are named: `p100`, `p101`, `p102`, `p103`, etc. For example, the `p100` contains:

`p100=[1;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;0;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;0;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;1;0;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1;1;0;1;1;1]`

What I want to do is match the ID of my participant 100 to the correct double variable (p100) by name, so that I can copy that double into a new variable (`desired_variable`). Here's what I have:

`desired_variable_name = who(strcat('p',num2str(ID)))`

It correctly outputs "p100", which is my desired double variable name. I cannot, however, understand how to call this variable from the workspace by it's name, so that I can copy its contents of zeros and ones (and not just the name) into the new variable `desired_variable` that I can work with later on. I tried different things with `find`, `disp`, the apparently nonexistent in this language "print", etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should (not) use [`eval`](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304528-tutorial-why-variables-should-not-be-named-dynamically-eval) for that

Comment: Could you specify the "not" part please? :)

Comment: check that link - it's basically about why not :)

Comment: Instead of variables `p100`, `p101`, etc, you could have a single cell array that you index: `p{100}`, `p{101}`, etc. Or alternatively make it into a [`dictionary`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dictionary.html) (since R2022b), or [`containers.Map`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/containers.map.html) for earlier versions of MATLAB. -- Basically what you are doing now is confusing code and data. The number in `p101` is data, and you hard-coded that into your code by creating a variable name with that number. Keep data and code separate at all times!

Comment: Hi Cris, thanks for the answer. I'm a bit confused about the last sentence and why ```p101``` is data. I should say that data names are different, but they contain an index, which I use. Sorry, new to this!

Comment: The number is the participant ID or something like that, right? That is data. Every participant has its own ID, if you add participants you add IDs. Do you want to rewrite your code every time you add a participant? Of course not! Thus, the IDs are data. If the code is unaware of specific IDs, but uses a variable to store the ID, and maybe a dictionary to link IDs to other bits of data, then you don't update your code every time a new participant joins. The name of a variable is code, a participant ID is data, thus the ID should not be part of the variable name.

Comment: Not quite. The data has a different name, longer than that. I just extracted from each file name the numerical index I'm interested in, so I could match it. So ID is not data, it's just a string in this case.

Comment: Oh, I think I inderstand what you mean. :) I should say, this is all part of a large loop, with other procedures in it, and I do overwrite ID for every participant, but then delete after every iteration. Same goes for the other variables, so it's not so much of a problem they overwite. Thank you for clarifying, though!

Comment: I agree with Chris Luengo. Lousy variable definitions leads to lousy code. Don't have variable names like P100, P101, etc. Reasons for this and much better alternatives (cell arrays, structs, etc.) can be found on the MATLAB Answers site under "TUTORIAL: Why Variables Should Not Be Named Dynamically (eval)". You should read this to understand why what you are currently doing is not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is for a single entry:

```
ID=100;
evalin('base',strcat('desired_variable_name=p',string(ID)))
```

i don't know what ID looks like but you can loop through it easily:

```
ID=100:110; %my guess of what ID looks like. 
for ii=1:numel(ID)
evalin('base',strcat('desired_variable_name_',string(ii),'=p',string(ii)));
end
```

is it a good idea to use evalin to generate variables and give values to them? no. You should reconsider the structure of the problem itself as commented by others.

**note**: if your goal is not to assign them in the base workspace but in the function one (you never specified if it is a script or a function), replace 'base' with 'caller'.

This question is a duplicate of what's on mathwork answers:
https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1936714-finding-a-double-in-the-workspace-by-name-and-assigning-it-to-a-new-variable?s_tid=srchtitle